# Spring beans are not detected in JAX-WS service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-ws, cxf

I am trying to consume a JAX-WS CXF webservice written by me. I always get nullPointerException for spring autowired annotated beans. However, everything works fine within serverSide over web, but accessing beans through JAX-WS CXF webservice.

I have tried by extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport, but still no luck. How can I do this.

regards,
Aqif

Comment: I think @WebService annotated classes are initialized by CXF not Spring and is not part of Spring Container. How can I link these together. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my answer :)

I had to add this to my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<!--Person Service Settings -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="personService"  implementor="#person" address="/personService" />
<bean id="person" class="com.service.PersonServiceImpl" />
<bean id="PersonDAO" class="com.dao.PersonDAOImpl"/>
<!--Person Service Settings -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Spring's `ContextLoaderListener`  in your `web.xml` ?

```
  <context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: I did added contextLoaderlistner, 

but It donot have context-params, what they are, what should be there in beans.xml?